# Keras, Python, Should I use data normalization on huge stock market dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, finance

Lately got concerned about which way to preprocess data? The dataset is huge, and some numbers differentiate with hundreds some of columns moving in scale 1-5?

As I read other works some people suggest that there is no needs to normalize data because dataset is too large.

Please can somebody confirm?

Comment: Personally I don't think you should apply normalization on stock date.

Comment: You may find help here http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic rather than on stackoverflow.